# Why have play framework templates access to private fields?

Tags: java, templates, playframework, private, access-modifiers

I have a class with a `private` field and suspected that the template could not access it without a `getX` method, but the value is displayed as if it would be `public`.

```
class Task {
  private String title = "";
}
```

The template can display the `title` with the following code:

```
${task.title}
```

I guess that is due to reflection magic, but shouldn't it be impossible to render private fields without a getter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework does generate the **setters and getters only for public fields**, but as the template language is Groovy and **Groovy seems to have no encapsulation**, the non-accessible field can be accessed without any restrictions from the template code.

I reported a bug, but I'm really not sure if that can be fixed, because Play 1.x relays on Groovy for its templates (for the upcoming 2.0 version, play will switch to Scala as language for the templates).

If your really need to restrict the access you should **take a look SecurityManagers**. They can prevent reflection on private fields, but I don't know how precise you can configure the restrictions.

---

- [github: PropertiesEnhancer (1.2.4) lines: 67-111, 189-196](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/f45fe8f6887be6e31bc0a2e3c106002f7ae87935/framework/src/play/classloading/enhancers/PropertiesEnhancer.java)
- [checkMemberAccess - SecurityManager (docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkMemberAccess%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29)

Answer (score 2):

my guess is that the framework is dynamically adding getter and setter methods.  Try making a String getTitle() method that returns "override" and you'll know for sure.

Comment: A `getTitle()` method is called, so it seems like Play is generating getters automatically. But the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/model#properties) says that this would only be done for any public, non-static, non-final field of a class.